# Set_fact dynamic variable name inside loop

Tags: ansible

I have a list of `accounts`, a dictionary `mappedsecrets` which has the `accounts` as keys, and a list of `secrets` as values and finally a dictionary `secrets` contains the secret-names and secret-values

```
#variables
accounts:
  acc_one
  acc_two

mappedsecrets:
  acc_one:
    - keyone
    - keytwo
  acc_two:
    - keythree
    - keyfour

secrets:
  keyone: secret_1
  keytwo: secret_2
  keythree: secret_3
  keyfour: secret_4
```

I have an include_task looping over accounts, with `loop_var:account`.
Inside the loop, I want to create a dict all key - secrets that the account has mapped:
so for example:

```
acc_one:
  keyone: secret_1
  keytwo: secret_2
```

I went the set_fact route, with the combine filter.

```
- name: "Create dict of account secrets"
  set_fact:
    account_secrets: "{{ account_secrets |default({}) | combine( {item: secrets[item]} ) }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ mappedsecrets[account] }}"
```

The problem is:

**each loop just keeps appending the `account_secrets` variable, which causes the last account have all the secrets from the previous iterations.**

(correct me if i'm wrong) I've read that it's not possible to reset facts inside an ansible-play.
So I figure I can make dynamic names, based on the loop iteration: like `account_secrets_{{ ansible_loop.index }}`

But I'm stuck figuring out the correct syntax for the below:

`set_fact:
    account_secrets_{{ ansible_loop.index }}: "{{ account_secrets_{{ ansible_loop.index }} |default({}) | combine( {item: secrets[item]} ) }}"`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
set_fact:
    account_secrets_{{ ansible_loop.index }}: "{{ lookup('vars', 'account_secrets_' + ansible_loop.index|string) |default({}) | combine( {item: secrets[item]} ) }}"
```

I'm still curious tho, is there a more 'ansible' way to achieve this use-case?